# How change default underline color in TextInputEditText

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, styles

my underline color in editText is primaryColor, I want to change it to another when it is out of focus.

xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/usernameInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="384dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/username_hint"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/usernameInputEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@color/primaryColor"
                android:text="@={authViewModel._username}"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

i tried

```
app:boxStrokeColor="color/blue"
```

but it works when editText is focused, in other word user is in editText, I want to when user isn't in editText line was  blue and when user is in editText line should be white

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line to your edittext

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
```

Comment: after that the whole box gets white not only line